# Removing encryption flag with signature flag unchanged in MS Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

For most e-mails that are encrypted and digitally signed, we can remove encryption in c# using mail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(PR_SECURITY_FLAGS,oldValue-1) or in Outlook interface (File->Properties->Encrypt message contents and attachments).

Such mail could be then saved without any problems. For small number of e-mails save operation generates pop-up “You have changed this message. If you save the changes, the message will no longer be digitally signed. Do you want to save your changes?”.

How to recognize e-mails which generates this pop-up before save action will be triggered (any flag or property that can be read before)? or maybe there is any way to achieve this using Outlook Redemption?

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the `PR_SECURITY_FLAGS` property until you are about to send the message.
Also, the property is a bit mask, so `oldValue-1` does not really make sense. If you want  to remove the lowest bit, use `oldValue & ~1`.

Comment: As mentioned I already read PR_SECURITY_FLAGS and I already knew that both bits (encryption and signature) were set. So my code is perfectly fine – it will always zeros encryption bit.
Also, I’m not going to send those messages. I’m processing mails that are in my Inbox. My script goes through all encrypted mails and creates their unencrypted copies without removing digital signatures. It works fine for hundreds of e-mails, but for a few of them it hangs as a save operation for such modified mail generates pop-up described in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

You must preserve existing security flags when you add or remove any other flags:

```
Sub SignAndEncrypt()
    Const PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003"
    Dim mi As MailItem
    Set mi = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Dim ulFlags As Long

    ulFlags = CLng(mi.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SECURITY_FLAGS))
    ulFlags = ulFlags Or &H1 ' SECFLAG_ENCRYPTED
    ulFlags = ulFlags Or &H2 ' SECFLAG_SIGNED
    mi.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty PR_SECURITY_FLAGS, ulFlags

    Set mi = Nothing
End Sub
```

The flags are:

- NONE (=0)
- SECFLAG_ENCRYPTED (=1)
- SECFLAG_SIGNED (=2)
- SECFLAG_ENCRYPTED & SECFLAG_SIGNED (=3)